# Minor "edit summary" display bug

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, edit-summary

On Electronics SE I try to edit a question asked by another user. I click "edit", change the text and click "save". A message "please enter a comment" is displayed.

I use the newest and the freshest version of Chrome (also reproed in Firefox 4) with default settings and forms auto-complete. So I click into the edit box, a drop-down with previous comments appears and from the drop-down I select my most often used comment ("smaller version of images to reduce traffic" - that's the most typical reason why I edit questions on Electronics SE).

Now the edit looks like this:

[image]

there's the "briefly explain your changes" phrasing and also the comment I selected (right beneath "briefly explain" text) but the comment is displayed so faintly that it's barely visible. If I click "save" at this point the changes are saved together with my selected comment.

I guess there's a minor bug somewhere in the page code that fails to reset the "briefly explain" phrasing when an item is selected in browser auto-complete.

Comment: Have you seen this in any other browser? FF4 is fairly outdated and may not (not sure...) be supported.

Comment: @M.Babcock on that very topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need (Not suggesting that FF4 is the problem here though)

Comment: @M.Babcock very true. Firefox 6 and earlier [are not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) by Stack Exchange network. (Same like IE6 for example - utterly outdated)

Comment: @M.Babcock: I've just reproduced this in the freshest version Chrome.

Comment: @sharptooth - +1 Fair enough.

Comment: There is a *huge* difference between Firefox 4 and IE 6, folks. Not to mention the fact that Microsoft hasn't gotten the versioning fever, causing their version numbers to increment each time they hiccup or change a pixel color in their icon. The changes in the rendering engine between FF 4 and FF 6 are quite minor.

Comment: @Cody I just meant both are equally unsupported by Stack Exchange.

Comment: +1 reproduced of FF 19.0. Nice catch!

Comment: FF 24.0 on Ubuntu 12.10. Still happening. Can't screenprint it (fixes itself as the where do you want to save it box comes up) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reproduced.

Note that pressing *any* key while focus is in the input box, or clicking anywhere that removes focus from that box will remove the "briefly explain..." text.

Comment: Is a a page code problem or a browser problem?

Comment: It's simply an issue of the code watching for a keypress or change (fired only when the box loses focus), and thus missing the insertion of an autocompleted bit of text.

Comment: Problem is there's probably no client side event triggered when user choose something from the auto complete list.

Comment: That said, can't you poke the devs to throw in a quick fix? :)

Comment: Will the fix ever be deployed for that?