# Bug in "edit summary" field

Tags: bug, edit-summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minor “edit summary” display bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126242/minor-edit-summary-display-bug)

When I edit a question (SO/Meta) I often end up doing similar things. So I only need to click the edit summary field and select an option saved by the browser:

> [image]

But when I do this the texts are mixed, and if I want to add more comments here it's all a blur:

> [image]

It's only when I leave the focus of the input field that I see the text correctly:

> [image]

I guess the error is in the jQuery and that the dfault text should disappear when you focus in on the input field. I'm using FireFox 16.